# Why Chern numbers (integral of Chern class) are integers?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, physics

I am a physics student trying to self-learn Chern numbers and Chern class. The book I am learning (Nakahara) introduces the total Chern class as an invariant polynomial of local curvature form $F$
$P(F) = \det (I + t\frac{{iF}}{{2\pi }}) = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^k {{t^r}{P_r}(F)} $
and each ${P_j}(F)$ defines the j-th Chern class ${c_j}(F) \in {H^{2j}}(M)$

The book didn't mention anything about the Chern number. According to some other material I found (may be wrong), the Chern number is defined as an integral over 2$r$-cycle,

$\int_\sigma  {{c_{{j_1}}}(F)}  \wedge {c_{{j_2}}}(F) \cdots {c_{{j_l}}}(F)  $

where  ${j_1} + {j_2} +  \cdots {j_l} = r$

The material also said that this integral is always an integer. Due to my limited knowlege, I cannot see how is this proved and I cannot find some reference that is easy enough to me. So can anybody help ?

Comment: Chern classes can be refined to integral cohomology classes. A good reference is the book "Characteristic classes" Milnor-Stasheff.

Comment: The Chern classes are Poincare duals   of certain integral  homology classes   described  by so called degeneracy loci. The   Chern numbers can then be  described  as intersection numbers of   integral homology classes. The  book of Griffiths  and Harris  discuses this in detail.

Comment: Thanks very much, it looks there is no simple way to show it, I will take a look of those book first .

Comment: Something relatively elementary that you shoud try to do: prove that the Chern classes (as defined in the question) do not depend on the choice of connection but only depend on the underlying complex vector bundle. This will show you the "topological nature" of the Chern classes and so make plausible some integrality property.

Comment: I know ${P_r}(F)-{P_r}(F')$ is exact, so in this sense the polynomials are independent of connection, is this what you mean?

Comment: almost by definition, Chern classes of a vector bundle are expressed as integral linear combinations of products  of Chern classes of line bundles; the latter are patently integral : these are the images of $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 5):

Although the question may be a bit borderline for this site, I thought I'd contribute an answer since I think that it is surprising (it certainly surprised me as a student). My understanding is that Chern arrived at his classes while trying to generalize the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. This theorem says that the integral of the Gaussian curvature of **any** metric on a compact surface equal $2\pi$ times the Euler characteristic. So in particular, the curvature normalized by $1/2\pi$ always integrates to an integer. But of course, the real explanation is the previous statement that this integral is topological in nature.

Jumping ahead to the present, the integrality of Chern numbers is an artifact of the fact that Chern classes can be defined purely topologically, in several ways, as classes in $H^{2*}(X,\mathbb{Z})$. I'm not really saying anything that hasn't already been said in the comments.